# Angular 6 - Passing messages via service to from component to message component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying out how to pass a message from `app.component.ts` to be displayed in `messageComponent.ts`

on `app.component.html` I have added `<app-messagecomponent></app-messagecomponent>`

Add the moment it's just showing nothing.

I also have a method in a service:

message.service.ts

```
message(message) {
    return message;
}
```

So what I want to do to pass a message from other components via the message service so it's displaying in the app-messagecomponent.html

For example from app.component.ts:

```
sendMessageToService() {
    this.myservice.message('my Message to be displayed in the messageComponent');
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you can check my answer if you want to pass message using a service to another component.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In this case to pass a message from one component to another component using a service , you can create a global message bus or event bus (`publish/subscribe pattern`).

For this we need the `Subject` (to emit values using `.next()` method) and `Observable` (to listen to the messages using `.subscribe()` ) from `Rxjs` which is now an essential part of angular 6. (For this example I am using Rxjs 6 along with rxjs-compat package)

Here we will be sending a message using `MessageService` class which is declared as `@Injectable` to inject as a dependency in component. The message will be emitted on a button click from `app.component.html` . The same message will be retrieved in `message.component.ts` to show it in the html template `message.component.html`. We will include the selector for `MessageComponent` which is `<app-messagecomponent></app-messagecomponent>`  in the `app.component.html`.

Here is the complete code below

**message.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable,Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }

    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';

  constructor(private service:MessageService){}

  sendMessage(): void {
        // send message to subscribers via observable subject
  this.service.sendMessage('Message from app Component to message Component!');   
  }

  clearMessage():void{
    this.service.clearMessage();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="sendMessage()">Click here to test message</button> <br><br>
<app-messagecomponent></app-messagecomponent>
```

**message.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-messagecomponent',
    templateUrl: 'message.component.html'
})

export class MessageComponent implements OnDestroy {
    message: any = {};
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
        // subscribe to app component messages
        this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**message.component.html**

```
<p>The incoming message :  </p>  <br>
{{message?.text }}
```

Here I have used Elvis operator in case the `message` is `undefined` .

Here is a working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-snaghl

Let me know if you are looking for something like this.

Comment: Nice explaination.

Comment: please provide me the example for to communicate two unrelated components sharing there information. And I am confused in folder structure also.(It needs to be two components with their own name and we must share data between them by using services.

Comment: this is nice explanation i got it but I want the explanation for two unrelated component example : Homecomponent and ProductDetailComponent... And I need to send data from home to prdouct details component...Please get back to me with your answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3669026 this is applicable for any component. not only parent child

Comment: Thanks niladri. It means that either it is parent child relationship or unrelated components for both the approaches it is applicable?

Comment: for both approaches

Comment: is not .subscribe deprecated now?

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran Sorry didn't get you .. do you mean unsubscribe()?

Comment: @Niladri the .subscribe method is deprecated now and I was going through all these examples. sometimes it works but sometimes it does not.

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran which version are you using?Rxjs and Angular

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran it's not obsolete only a particular signature is obsolete. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback

Comment: as i have commented there, now it turns out all that functions are marked obselete.

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran works perfectly for Rxjs 6.5.4 https://stackblitz.com/edit/fromfetch-jxvurn?file=index.ts

Comment: Let me try this code. I am having issues with same code in NGX-ADMIN dashboard

Answer (score 2):

you can use input for the same

< app-messagecomponent [YourInputVariableName]=
"YourMessage" >< /app-messagecomponent>

in app.compnent write

**YourMessage:any='my Message to be displayed in the messageComponent';**

in app-message.component write

**@Input YourInputVariableName:any;**

you can print message in app-messagecomponent by **this.YourInputVariableName**

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-interconnect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-interconnect) library. This allows sending data form any angular entity to another.

You can do broadcasting or receiving from multiple points.

Broadcasting example -

> ````
> let messageStream: IMessageStream = createBroadcaster('home/stateChanged');   //Create a broadcaster```
>  
>  ...
>  ...
>  /*Receive from it from another component somewhere in the hierarchy*/
>  
>  let userReceiver = receiveFrom('home/stateChanged', 'contacts/user', (data, error, complete) => {
>   console.log(data);
>   console.log(error);
>   console.log(complete);
>  })
>  
>  
>  '''
>  '''
>  /*Broadcast messages from the first component*/
>  nessageStream.emit('logged-in');
> ````