# Saving product info using Services

Tags: angular

Hello there dear coders,
I have a project that i have to save some products as favorites in favorite component section, I must save them to a service then call it from that specific component, anyone can help how to do that in real time and asynchronously ? any guide or clue would be enough and appreciated.

Comment: Be specific while asking question. This question already has an answer @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371582/angular-6-passing-messages-via-service-to-from-component-to-message-component

Comment: this answer that you have mentioned is similar to what i asked but in specific i want to get some data information and show it inside another component in the same time just like shopping cart in e-commerce websites

Answer (score 1):

For this I would consider using a `BehaviorSubject` in your service. Something like this would allow you to update the Subject via the component and see it update on the UI in real time.

This is how I have set up a simple working example:

`favorite.service.ts`

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class FavoriteService {

    public favs = new BehaviorSubject([]);

    constructor() { }

    public updateSubject(newItem: any[]): void {
        this.favs.next(newItem)
    }

}
```

`favorite.component.ts`

```
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {

    public favorites = this.service.favs;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const items = ['item1', 'item2'];
        this.service.updateSubject(items);
    }

}
```

The you can see the updated array in your html as follows:

`favorite.component.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of favorites.value">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

So whenever you call the updateSubject method it will update the behaviour subject with a new array and any items added/changed should appear on you html straight away.